# PHP parsing/typecasting problems

Tags: php, parsing, casting

What I'm trying to do is to convert some archived CSV data. It all worked well on a couple thousand files. I parse out a date and convert it to a timestamp. However on one file, somehow it doesn't work. I use `(int) $string` to cast the parsed strings to int values -> it returns `int(0)`. I also used `intval()` -> same result. When I use `var_dump($string)`, I get some weird output, for example `string(9) "2008"`, which actually should be `string(4) "2008"`. I tried to get to use `preg_match` on the string, without success. Is this an encoding problem?

Here is some code, it's just pretty standard stuff:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$ms = 0;
function convert_csv($filename)
{
$target = "tmp.csv";
$fp = fopen("$filename","r") or die("Can't read the file!");
$fpo = fopen("$target","w") or die("Can't read the file!");
while($line = fgets($fp,1024))
{
    $linearr = explode(",","$line");

    $time = $linearr[2];
    $bid = $linearr[3];
    $ask = $linearr[4];
    $time = explode(" ",$time);
    $date = explode("-",$time[0]);
    $year = (int) $date[0]);
    $month =  (int)$date[1];
    $day = (int)$date[2];
    $time = explode(":",$time[1]);

    $hour = (int)$time[0];
    $minute = (int)$time[1];
    $second = (int)$time[2];
    $time = mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year);

    if($ms >= 9)
    {
        $ms = 0;
    }else
    {
        $ms ++;
    }
    $time = $time.'00'.$ms;
    $newline = "$time,$ask,$bid,0,0\n";
    fwrite($fpo,$newline);

}
fclose($fp);
fclose($fpo);
unlink($filename);
rename($target,$filename);
```

}

Here is a link to the file we are talking about:

- http://ratedata.gaincapital.com/2008/04%20April/EUR_USD_Week1.zip

Comment: Please show us some code. Also you got `string(9) "2008"` ?

Comment: A hex dump of the string(s) would certainly be a good idea, since the seemingly too-high string length indicates there are some bytes in there that your output viewer can't or won't show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file seems to be encoded in [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), so it is indeed an encoding problem. The `string(9)` is caused by the null-bytes that you get if UTF-16 is interpreted as a single-byte encoding.

This makes the file hard to read with functions like `fgets`, since they are binary-safe and thus not encoding aware. You could read the entire file in memory and perform an encoding conversion, but this is horribly inefficient.

I'm not sure if it's possible to read the file properly as UTF-16 using native PHP functions. You might need to write or use an external library.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to convert your file to plan ascii using iconv.

If you are on a linux or similar system that has iconv command:

$ iconv -f UTF16 -t ASCII EUR_USD_Week1.csv > clean.csv

Otherwise you may found the PHP iconv function useful:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php